# Generate a timetable using MySQL ,stuck at inserting records into to the table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, rdbms

I want to generate a timetable.Three tables have been created.

```
create table subjects(subjectid int primary key,subjectname varchar (30));
insert into subjects values(1,'sub1');
insert into subjects values(2,'sub2');
insert into subjects values(3,'sub3');
insert into subjects values(4,'sub4');
insert into subjects values(5,'sub5');
insert into subjects values(6,'sub6');
```

---

```
create table Days(days varchar(30));
insert into Days values('mon');
insert into Days values('tue');
insert into Days values('wed');
insert into Days values ('thu');
insert into Days values ('fri');
insert into Days values ('sat');
```

Finally the timetable to which these subjects and days goes into:

```
create table timetable(days varchar(30),slot1 varchar(10),slot2 varchar(10), slot3 varchar(10), 
                      slot4 varchar(10), slot5 varchar(10), slot6 varchar(10));
insert into timetable(days)
select days from Days;
insert into timetable(slot1)
select distinct subjectname from subjects;
select * from timetable;
```

I need to create a timetable such that each row/column is distinct and the same subjects must not repeat twice in the same column. Using DISTINCT gave me the result but with all the other columns NULL.When I tried to insert to all the  other columns it have me "not enough values" error.
What are the concepts that has to be learnt to complete this?
Also what if there are multiple sections and semesters how to insert without any clash between subject/teachers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you can be confident that your schema design is sub-optimal; a database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO timetable (days)
SELECT days
FROM Days;
UPDATE timetable 
  JOIN Days ON timetable.days = Days.days
  JOIN subjects ON Days.dayid MOD 6 = (subjects.subjectid + 0) MOD 6
SET timetable.slot1 = subjects.subjectname;
UPDATE timetable 
  JOIN Days ON timetable.days = Days.days
  JOIN subjects ON Days.dayid MOD 6 = (subjects.subjectid + 1) MOD 6
SET timetable.slot2 = subjects.subjectname;
UPDATE timetable 
  JOIN Days ON timetable.days = Days.days
  JOIN subjects ON Days.dayid MOD 6 = (subjects.subjectid + 2) MOD 6
SET timetable.slot3 = subjects.subjectname;
UPDATE timetable 
  JOIN Days ON timetable.days = Days.days
  JOIN subjects ON Days.dayid MOD 6 = (subjects.subjectid + 3) MOD 6
SET timetable.slot4 = subjects.subjectname;
UPDATE timetable 
  JOIN Days ON timetable.days = Days.days
  JOIN subjects ON Days.dayid MOD 6 = (subjects.subjectid + 4) MOD 6
SET timetable.slot5 = subjects.subjectname;
UPDATE timetable 
  JOIN Days ON timetable.days = Days.days
  JOIN subjects ON Days.dayid MOD 6 = (subjects.subjectid + 5) MOD 6
SET timetable.slot6 = subjects.subjectname;
```

I have added PK column into `Days` table.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ba8bdea90f17fe4769901727e14680d)